# SKPhysicsBody does not have a member named "your variable"

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm getting an error within my code. I thought I called contact.bodyA but isnt reading it so far. Am I missing something or using the if statement all wrong? I'm a new programmer so sorry if this is super easy or if its vague. Let me know if you need more information! Thanks in advance!

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsBody!){

    // Body1 and 2 depend on the categoryBitMask << 0 and << 1
    var firstBody:SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody:SKPhysicsBody

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask){ ERROR- (SKPhysicsBody does not have a member named'bodyA')
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }else{
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if ((firstBody.contactTestBitMask & photonTorpedoCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.contactTestBitMask & alienCategory) != 0){
        torpedoDidCollideWithAlien(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, alien: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because contact isn't supposed to be a `SKPhysicsBody`; it is supposed to be a `SKPhysicsContact` object. SKPhysicsBody does not have a member named `bodyA` (or `bodyB`), because they are members of `SKPhysicsContact`.

The correct declaration for your `didBeginContact` function should look like:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    //Your code in here
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thanks a lot I would of never knew that!

Answer (score -2):

Try that :

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsBodyContact!){

    // Body1 and 2 depend on the categoryBitMask << 0 and << 1
    var firstBody:SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody:SKPhysicsBody

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }else{
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if ((firstBody.contactTestBitMask & photonTorpedoCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.contactTestBitMask & alienCategory) != 0){
        torpedoDidCollideWithAlien(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, alien: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)
    }
}
```